# Why does the tan inverse integral have a 1/a but not the sin inverse one?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

$$\begin{align*}
\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{a^2-u^2}} &= \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{a}\right) + K\\
\int \frac{du}{a^2+u^2} &= \frac{1}{a}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{u}{a}\right) + K \end{align*}$$

Always wondered why but I had no idea.

Comment: for the first: $du(a^2-u^2)^{-1/2}=a^{-1}du(1-(u/a)^2)^{-1/2}$, but substituting $t=u/a\implies dt=a^{-1}\,du\implies du=a\,dt$, so the factor of $a^{-1}$ *disappears*! for the second: $du(a^2+u^2)^{-1}=a^{-2}du(1+(u/a)^2)^{-1}$, and substituting $t=u/a$ now leaves a factor of $a^{-1}$.

Comment: @wizzwizz4: the sarcasm is unnecessary. I see you have no reputation here, so perhaps you are not aware how frequently straightforward answers are left in the comments, especially when the question is too simple, or when the answer is too obvious. my comment is not a complete answer because I didn't explain what the substitutions are good for: that is the hint left for the OP.

Comment: @symplectomorphic That was not intended to be sarcasm, sorry. I have deleted my comment. I was going by [this meta post from 2012](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4134/316841).

Comment: @wizzwizz4: the reasoning in that meta post does not apply here, because the OP had already accepted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the latter, you have $\dfrac{1}{a}\cdot d\left(\dfrac{u}{a}\right)= \dfrac{du}{a^2}$ while the former you have $\dfrac{du}{a} = d\left(\dfrac{u}{a}\right)$. The $\dfrac{1}{a}$ shows up to balance the $a^2$ at the denominator.

Answer (score 9):

I think the most intuitive way to think of this is in terms of dimensional analysis.

Since $u^2$ and $a^2$ are added, they must have the same dimensions, so $u$ and $a$ must as well. Say, for specificity, that $u$ and $a$ are both lengths.

Then the left integrand is dimensionless (as $du$ and $\sqrt{a^2-u^2}$ are both lengths), so it can integrate to a pure number. But the right integrand has units of inverse length (as $a^2+u^2$ is an *area*). So it must integrate to some quantity which also has units of inverse length; as $a$ is the only constant around with units of length, it's natural to write this as $\frac{1}{a}$ times some function of $u$ which is a pure number.